# Python cmd2 module send commands

Tags: python, python-2.7, command-line

I have implemented a custom command line with python cmd2 module.

```
from cmd2 import Cmd
class CliApp(Cmd):
      .....
```

Now I also need to send commands to my custom command line from other python project.
I tried:

```
send = CliApp().send
print send('hello')
```

Which gives the error:

> AttributeError: Cmd instance has no attribute 'send'

I have also tried the original example from:

[cmd2 - the-send-method](http://www.phyast.pitt.edu/~micheles/python/cmd2.html#the-send-method) - but it gives the same error.

Answer (score 0):

The python cmd2 module which was originally developed by [Catherine Devlin](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/cmd2) around 2008 and has a project page on GitHub under python-cmd2/cmd2 appears to be a completely separate entity from cmd2 module developed around the same time frame by [Michele Simionato](http://www.phyast.pitt.edu/~micheles/python/cmd2.html).

You can read the documentation for the cmd2 module which you can install from PyPI at cmd2.rtfd.io and note that it does NOT have a **send** method.

To accomplish what you want, I would suggest looking at the cmd2 source code for the **onecmd_plus_hooks** method and at the cmd2 unit tests which call this method via the **run_cmd** helper in conftest.py.